# How to set Java truststore and truststorepassword properties for particular project in tomcat?

Tags: https, tomcat8, truststore, java-security

I'm running two applications in tomcat and tomcat is running on https. I need to send certificate for application1 and application2 doesn't need it. I'm configuring the truststore and truststorepassword in application1 to consume services from server 'x'. When the system properties are configured the second application is sending the certificate so i'm getting exception from the server 'y'(doesn't need any certificate to access the server from second application). How can i solve this problem ?

Added security-constraint element in application2 web.xml to disable SSL option for url pattern:

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ShipConsoleSCMCloud</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/application2/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use system properties.

Depending on which API you are using to communicate with the service, it should have configuration options to configure the TLS parameters specifically for one connection rather than just picking-up the system properties as defaults.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can we configure TLS parameters specifically for one connection in tomcat?  - @mark-thomas

Comment: That would depend on the API you are using to communicate with the service.